# One word for something that works well?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a single word for something that works well or something that doesn’t work well as interventions.

I don’t not want to use *efficient* or *proper* because these describe the person or the process, not the intervention.

Comment: Are you looking for **solution** ?

Comment: Effective/ineffective.

Answer (score 2):

**functional**

> in working order or operating
>   3. *capable of functioning; working* ([CD](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/functional?showCookiePolicy=true))

**dysfunctional**

> not working properly or normally ([LDCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dysfunctional))

Answer (score 1):

**[effective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/effective)** - Successful in producing a desired or intended result

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers already given, here's another idea:

**successful** - marked by a favorable outcome (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/successful)

**unsuccessful**